# ¿Por qué selenium no localiza el objeto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scrapping

Estoy tratando de scrapear la web de vehiculos de ocasión de mercedes, url de ejemplo:
https://www.mercedes-benz.es/passengercars/mercedes-benz-cars/vehicle-search.html/u/used-vehicles/s/search-vehicles/?salesClass=Clase%20A&firstRegistrationDate=20190101-20220905&brand=Mercedes-Benz&transmissionType=Cambio%20autom%C3%A1tico&powerKW=110-225&line=AMG%20Line

Para probar intento hacer click al botón de aceptar las cookies.
He añadido otra prueba clickando a un botón que muestra más resultados. Me dan error ambas, veo que al cargar la página cuando carga los resultados carga como "una herramienta interna" al tiempo de cargar la web ¿Puede tener que ver? ¿Cómo puedo conseguir acceder a los datos?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def set_browser():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    load_page(driver)
    return driver

def load_page(driver):
    url = "https://www.mercedes-benz.es/passengercars/mercedes-benz-cars/vehicle-search.html/u/used-vehicles/s/search-vehicles/?salesClass=Clase%20A&firstRegistrationDate=20190101-20220504&mileage=2300-80000&powerKW=120-225&fuelType=Gasolina&transmissionType=Cambio%20autom%C3%A1tico&line=AMG%20Line&sort=offerPriceGross&order=desc"
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(10)

def start(driver):
    try:
        cookies = driver.find_element('xpath', '/div/div/div[2]/cmm-buttons-wrapper/div/div/button[3]')
        cookies.click()
    except:
        print("Fallo cookies")
    
    try:
        show_more = driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/vs/div/div/div/div[1]/div/section/section[3]/div[2]/wb-load-more/wb-button-control/button')
        show_more.click()
        sleep(3)
    except:
        print("Fallo mostrar más")
     
def main():
    driver = set_browser()
    start(driver)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: yo tambien intente usar selenium en chrome pero los errores que arroja en busqueda de elementos es muy frecuente. nunca descubri que lo causa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la página, el XPATH string del boton "Aceptar todas" (las cookies) es otro.

Es este según la página:

```
/html/body/aside/cmm-cookie-banner//div/div/div[2]/cmm-buttons-wrapper/div/div/button[3]
```

Tu código debe quedar modificado asi:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

cookies = driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH,
    '/html/body/aside/cmm-cookie-banner//div/div/div[2]/cmm-buttons-wrapper/div/div/button[3]')
```